# What is `params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)` doing in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

All the examples of strong parameters in Rails 4 docs use

```
params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
```

Could someone please deconstruct and explain what is occurring with `require` and `permit` here?

Comment: This example comes directly from the documentation, which explains `permit` but not `require`.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

The `params` in a controller looks like a Hash, but it's actually an instance of [`ActionController::Parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html), which provides several methods such as `require` and `permit`.

The [`require`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) method ensures that a specific parameter is present, and if it's not provided, the `require` method throws an error. It returns an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` for the key passed into `require`.

The [`permit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) method returns a copy of the parameters object, returning only the permitted keys and values. When creating a new ActiveRecord model, only the permitted attributes are passed into the model.

It looks a lot like the whitelisting that was formerly included in ActiveRecord models, but it makes more sense for it to be in the controller.

Comment: The description of permit is a bit off: permit returns another hash that contains only the permitted key AND (this is critical) will respond with `true` to the `permitted?` method. By default, an instance of the `ActionController::Parameters` class will return `false` for `permitted?` Responding `true` to `permitted?` means the parameter object can be used in mass assignment; else the app will throw a ForbiddenAttributes error.

Comment: Does chaining `permit` on `require` also permit and include the required parameters in the returned object?

Comment: I find the naming unfortunate, as require does a lot more than making a permitted parameter required. Using params.permit(:person, :name, :age) does not work, and generates errors like "Unpermitted parameters: :utf8" for a typical form.

Answer (score 23):

Think of `require` as validation and `permit` as filtering.

- `require` will return the params under the given key if present, or raise
- `permit` will return the params filtered on the given keys*

Examples based on  https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/permit

```
>> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(user: { name: "Francesco", age: 22, role: "admin" })
{
    "user" => {
        "name" => "Francesco",
         "age" => 22,
        "role" => "admin"
    }
}

>> params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age)
Unpermitted parameter: role
{
    "name" => "Francesco",
     "age" => 22
}

>> params.require(:user)
{
    "name" => "Francesco",
     "age" => 22,
    "role" => "admin"
}

>> params.require(:user).permit(:foo)
Unpermitted parameters: name, age, role
{}

>> params.require(:person)
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: person

>> params.permit(:user)
Unpermitted parameter: user
{}
```

* Note that `permit` only allows certain scalars to pass the filter, as seen in the last example. The associated data must be of type `String`, `Symbol`, `NilClass`, `Numeric`, `TrueClass`, `FalseClass`, `Date`, `Time`, `DateTime`, `StringIO`, `IO`, `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` or `Rack::Test::UploadedFile`. Everything else, including containers like `Array` and `Hash`, are filtered out.

Answer (score 11):

To be more precise, when you create for eg. doing `.new(...)`, there must be `:person` hash indicated by require and the person hash will only accept `:name` and `:age` indicated by permit.

Example:

```
.new(person: { name: "Bhojendra", age: 32 }) // okay
.new(person: { name: "Rauniyar" }) // okay
.new(person: { name: "Bhojendra", other: 'asdf' }) // not okay, other not permitted
.new(person: { full_name: "Bhojendra Rauniyar" }) // not okay, full_name not permitted
.new(detail: { name: "Bhojendra", age: 32 }) // not okay, must be person
```

Comment: What do 3rd and 4th `not okay` example visualize?

Comment: @p0k8_ I edited the answer to clarify that. Those examples show some different field names which were not "permitted".