# How can I add to my params in Rails 5.1.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I have the following code that I use for sorting my table on my website.  It was working in `Rails 4.2`, but after upgrading to `Rails 5.1.4` it fails.  As it should from what I've read in the changes for Rails 5. Though I understand due to the changes it's breaking I still don't understand how to tweak this method to get it working again, and would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me and explain.  Thanks!

```
def roster_sort_link(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  icon = sort_direction == "asc" ? "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" : "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"
  icon = column == sort_column ? icon : ""
  link_to "#{title} <span style='font-size: 10px;' class='#{icon}'></span>".html_safe, params.merge({column: column, direction: direction})
end
```

The issue comes in the last line of the method where it states:

`params.merge({column: column, direction: direction})`

The error I'm getting is the following:

`unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424671/what-is-params-requireperson-permitname-age-doing-in-rails-4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on information I was given by @anothermh, I ended up doing this which seems to have worked.

From:

```
params.merge({column: column, direction: direction})
```

To:

```
params.permit(:column, :direction).merge({column: column, direction: direction})
```